# CSS Page Counter - Don't count first and last page of pdf

Tags: css, pdf, counter

I need help with a counter to show the amount of pages except for the first and last page in a pdf.
So far I've got:

```
@page {
  margin: 1.3cm 2cm 1.8cm 2cm;
  @bottom-right{
    content: counter(page) "/" counter(pages);
    }
}
@page:first {
  counter-reset: page 0 ;
  @bottom-right{
    content: ""
    }
}
```

If a document has 7 pages, I only need the counter to count starting on page 2, but with page number 1.

```
PAGE 1 = no counter
PAGE 2 = 1/5
PAGE 3 = 2/5
PAGE 4 = 3/5
PAGE 5 = 4/5
PAGE 6 = 5/5
PAGE 7 = no counter
```

Comment: The PDF that is created here is a combination of a letter (Page 1), a list of items the recipient should fill out and send back (pages 2-5, in this example) and an info sheet as last page.